# Integrate another dashboard with userFrosting

Tags: userfrosting

I am building a web project and using UserFrosting for the backend, it comes with SB admin as a dashboard, but I want to change it with another dashboard built with AngularJS or maybe static HTML, something like that : 
https://github.com/tui2tone/flat-admin-bootstrap-templates
So is this possible ? and if yes, how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned SB Admin, I guess you're using UserFrosting v0.3.x
Changing the dashboard only requires to edit the `userfrosting/templates/themes/default/dashboard.twig` file.

Using the new UserFrosting V4, it's simple as overwriting the template file in a custom Sprinkle. If you didn't start working on your project yet, you should really check out V4 (which use a new, [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com) based template).